# accessing textbox data in a wpf app from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple wpf application which has a few textboxes as the GUI. The application listens to a message queue and a new class is created that handles the messages as they appear (done via the simple service bus framework). This class that is created on the fly needs to access the text in the textboxes of the GUI. I’d also like to set text in the GUI from this class to say it’s done some work. My question is, what is the best way for this new class to access the existing main GUI class?

Answer (score 1):

Your main GUI class could have a ViewModel class as it's dataContext.

In your ViewModel class you would have a ObservableCollection as a property and you would add instances of MessageClass to this collection.

In th GUI you would have a some listView or whatever you wan't to display your messages bound to this Collection ( or a CollectionView of it ).

When an ObservableCollection get's a new object added it should let the GUI know to update itself automatically.